# Lift load Dateformat issue from csv file

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw

we are migrating db2 data to db2 on cloud. We are using below lift cli operation for migration.

- 1. Extracting a database table to a CSV file using `lift extract` from source database.
- 2. Then loading the extracted CSV file to db2 on cloud using 'lift load'

ISSUE:

We have created some tables using ddl on the target db2oncloud which have some columns with DATA TYPE "TIMESTAMP"
while load operation(lift load), we are getting below error"

> "MESSAGE": "The field in row \"2\", column \"8\" which begins with
>   \"\"2018-08-08-04.35.58.597660\"\" does not match the user specified
>   DATEFORMAT, TIMEFORMAT, or TIMESTAMPFORMAT. The row will be
>   rejected.",   "SQLCODE": "SQL3191W"

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on https://serverfault.com/ . Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for questions that may be asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use db2 as a source database, then use either:

- the following property during export (to export dates, times, timestamps as usual for db2 utilities - without double quotes):

source-database-type=db2

- try to use the following property during load, if you have already
  exported timestamps surrounded by double quotes:

timestamp-format="YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FFFFFF"

Answer (score 0):

If the data was extracted using `lift extract` then for sure you should load the data with `source-database-type=db2`. Using this parameter will preconfigure all the necessary load details automatically.